# My App is not installed in FIrefox OS Simulaator

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-os

I developed a simple application for FIrefox OS and I want to sumulate it on Firefox OS Simulator. When I load my application it, I get **Validation: OK** but my app is not installed in the simulator. I saw the same question here before, but the other guy's problem was that his manifest file had an incorrect name, but mine is named manifest.webapp. Here is my code:

manifest.webapp

```
 {
  "name": "Ejemplo Computo Movil",
  "description": "Your new awesome Open Web App",
  "launch_path": "/index.html",
  "icons": {
    "16": "/app-icons/icon-16.png",
    "48": "/app-icons/icon-48.png",
    "128": "/app-icons/icon-128.png"
  },
  "developer": {
    "name": "Eugenio Kuri Sainz",
    "url": "http://yourawesomeapp.com"
  },
  "permissions": {
    "desktop-notification": {
      "description": "Necesario para la creación de las notificaciones del sistema."
      }
  },
  "locales": {
    "es": {
      "description": "Ejemplo de aplicación Open Web",
      "developer": {
        "url": "http://yourawesomeapp.com"
      }
    },
    "it": {
      "description": "Il vostro nuovo fantastico Open Web App",
      "developer": {
        "url": "http://yourawesomeapp.com"
      }
    }
  },
  "default_locale": "en"
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Ejemplo de aplicación para IOS</title>

    <!--[if le IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
      <script src="scripts/respond.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- The following two elements pull in the styles for the default template functionality  -->

    <link href="styles/install-button.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="styles/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Below is your custom application stylesheet -->

    <link href="styles/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>

  <p>Esta es una aplicaci&oacute;n para IOS</p>

  <button id="install-btn">Install app</button>

<!-- The following element pulls in the script for the default template functionality -->

<script src="scripts/install.js"></script>  

<!-- Below is your custom application script -->

<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

index and manifest are on the same folder.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your manifest.webapp is alright. Please try by re-installing the simulator. And Remember to download the latest **Stable Simulator**